# How to read attachment messages without using scriptlets in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, attachment, jakarta-mail

I want to know how can I read attachment messages without using scriplets in JSP? After getting Message object as an attribute by using request object from servlets, how can I confirm whether Message content is an instance of Multipart or not without using scriplets like:

```
 if(message.getContent() instanceOf Multipart)
```

How can I read the content of any file by using EL in JSP? As I can't see any getRead method in inputStream subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add those getters to the `Message` class yourself:

```
public boolean isMultipart() {
    return (getContent() instanceof Multipart);
}

public String getContentAsString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    // Append using BufferedReader/InputStreamReader. If necessary, do it lazily.
    return builder.toString();
}
```

This way you can use it in JSTL/EL:

```
<c:if test="${message.multipart}">
    <c:out value="${message.contentAsString}" />
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform this logic in the servlet as well, and "send" only data that will be used for presentation to the jsp. In this case send:

- a `boolean` indicating whether there are attachments
- the list of attachments